# Calculate number of subsets

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I want to find how many subsets $A$ contains the set $\{ 1,2, \dots, 7 \}$ with the property  $$(3 \in A \iff 2 \in A).$$

The set $\{ 1,2, \dots, 7\}$ has in total $2^7=128$ subsets, right?

In order to find the number of subsets $A$ with the property $(3 \in A \iff 2 \in A)$, we have to find the number of subsets that do not contain both $2$ and $3$ and subtract the result by $128$, right?

But how do we find the number of subsets of $\{ 1,2, \dots, 7 \}$ that do not conatin both $2$ and $3$ ?

Comment: You need to find the number of subsets that contain both 2, and 3, and the number of subsets that contain neither 2, nor 3.

Comment: Ah yes. But how can we find these numbers of subsets? @amWhy

Comment: Hint: Remove $2,3$ from the set, so you are left with $5$ elements and the number of subsets of the new set is $2^5$.

Comment: @AnuragA So $2^5$ is the number of subsets that contain neither 2, nor 3. The number of subsets that contain both 2, and 3 is also $2^5$ because there are two possibilities for each of the rest of the numbers, right?

Comment: Don't you just want to count the subsets of the form $\{2,3\} \cup X$ where $X \subseteq \{1,4,5,6,7\}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you either want subsets that have $2$ and $3$ in or sets with neither. One way to think about this would be to consider $2$ and $3$ as a single object (which is either in or out). So then you are thinking of subsets of the following six objects: $\{1,2/3,4,5,6,7\}$.

The reasoning that you have already explained will tell you how to work out the number of subsets of this six element set.

Comment: So there are $2$ possibilities for the numbers $1,4,5,6,7$ and thus the desired number of subsets is $2^5$, right? @SimonTerrington

Comment: @Evinda there are 2 possibilities for each of $1,4,5,6,7$ individually and then there are two possibilities for $2/3$ combined, yielding $2^6$ total, not $2^5$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, I see!!!

Comment: And then $2$ possibilities for the $2/3$ object which will take you to $2^{6}$. This is nice because it gives the same answer as @gimusi below but just in a different way. It is basically a set of $6$ objects with $2^{6}$ subsets rather than (as you calculated above) the $2^{7}$ you subsets that you would have from a set of $7$ objects.

Comment: Thanks you both :)

Comment: It's a pleasure :)

Answer (score 4):

As noticed in the comments we need to find the number of subsets that contain both $2$ and $3$ and the number of subsets that contain neither $2$ nor $3$.

We have that

- the number of subsets with both $2$ and $3$ can be obtained by $2^5$ indeed
- the number of subsets not containing $2$ nor $3$ can be obtained by $2^5$ indeed.

Comment: In the first case the empty set is not included (but the whole set is). In the second case the empty set is included (but the whole set is not).

Comment: @SimonTerrington Yes of course! Thanks I've fixed that.

Comment: That's cool. Now we both get the same answer in interesting different ways :)

Comment: So, in total there are $2^5$ number of subsets with the property $(2 \in A \iff 3 \in A)$, right? @gimusi

Comment: @Evinda no, there are $2^5$ where $2$ and $3$ are both included and $2^5$ where $2$ and $3$ are both excluded.  Adding these gives the total as $2^5+2^5=2\cdot 2^5 = 2^6$.

Comment: @Evinda We have $2^5+2^5=2\cdot2^5=2^6$ which agrees with the clever interpretation given by Simon.

Comment: Nice, thank you :)

Comment: @Evinda You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

> "we have to find the number of subsets that do not contain both 2 and
>   3 and subtract the result by 128, right?"

That's one way to do it.  But it's probably easier to find the number of subsets that *do* contain both and the the number that contain neither and add those up.

The number that contain *both* must contain $2$ or $3$ and may or may not contain the remaining $5$ so that that is $2^5 = 32$.  And the sets that contain neither may or may not contain the remaining $5$ so that is $2^5 = 32$.  So there are $64$ than contain either both or neither.

We *could* attempt to find those that contain one or or the other but not both.  There are $2$ options whether it contains $2$ or whether it contains $3$.  And for the remaining $5$ there are $2^5=32$ ways it may contain any combination of those.  So there are $2*32  =64$ ways it can contain one or the other but not both.  ANd therefore $128 - 64 = 64$ ways it can contains both or neither.

Perhaps to make this less symmetric.  Suppose it were the set $\{1,....,10\}$ and $A$ is the set that it contains $2,3$ or $4$ if and only if it contains all three.  Then either it contains all three of them (there is $2^7=128$ ways this can occur) or it contains none (there are $2^7=18$ ways this can occur) so there are $128 + 128 = 256$ ways this can occur.

Alternatively we can say.  There $2^7=128$ options as to whether it contains $1,5,6...$ and two options whether it contains all or none of the remaining three so there are $2*128 = 256$ ways to do this.

If we attempt to calculate how many ways it can contain $1$ or $2$ but not all $3$ and not none of the three.  There are ${3\choose 1} =3$ ways we can choose one of $2,3,4$ and there are ${3\choose 2} =3$ ways we can choose two of $2,3,4$.  And of the remaining seven there are $2^7 = 128$ ways to choose them so there are $(3+3)*128 = 768$ to choose one or two of $2,3,4$.  And so there are $2^10 - 768 = 256$ ways to choose either all three or none.